# How to know what class is running in Unix?

Tags: java, unix, solaris

I have a class that is being executed through a script in unix (Solaris 9). Inside of the script the class is being run like this:

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH myPackage.component.MyMainClass $PROPERTIES_PATH/myMainClassProperties.properties
```

That shell needs to be monitored in order to see whether it works correctly or it fails, and it also is going to be run parallel with a different parameter file. So, my questions are:

- How can I know what class is being executed if I use *top*. Is that possible?**
- Is there a way to uniquely identify the class so it doesn't crash when running parallel?
- Will it always be shown as `myPackage.component.MyMainClass` in the table of processes?

When I say parallely, I refer to something like:

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH myPackage.component.MyMainClass $PROPERTIES_PATH/myMainClassProperties.properties
```

and in another window/session/job

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH myPackage.component.MyMainClass $PROPERTIES_PATH/mySomeOtherProperties.properties
```

**When I say so, is because top shows something like this:

```
PID USERNAME    THR PRI NICE    SIZE    RES STATE   TIME    CPU COMMAND
8545    batman  47  4   10  190M    112M    sleep   0:04:00 0.07%   java
9022    joker   91  4   10  286M    211M    sleep   0:01:00 0.09%   java
```

Comment: You need to use some sort of debugger kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was possible to get the info using `ptree | grep java` or `ptree | grep MyMainClass`

It lists a tree of the processes that are being executed as well as the command that is being runned in there for example:

```
13456 ksh 
    123476 java -cp java -cp /classpath/fullpath myPackage.component.MyMainClass /full/properties/path/myMainClassProperties.properties
```

The first line is a shell script, and inside it (next line) calls the java jar. This works for Solaris 9.

Thanks @Angelo-Neuschitzer for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

You can let `top` tell you the complete command, that will include any arguments you pass to the `VM`.

Also `ps` will give you the complete command as well (with the matching arguments).

In my debian I can switch the displayed command with the `c` toggle (start top and hit `c` until it shows the whole command)

for `ps` I use the arguments `-ef` (but `-f`) alone should do for that situation.

You may want to read the output of `man ps` and `man top`

Comment: Hi, well, if is possible that would be awesome. That way, I think it will be easier to monitor.

Comment: @StrayChild01 No problem, I just need to know what flavor you use (like 'which unix')

Comment: Hi Angelo, I tried both. When I hit c within top, it said command not recognized. When I tried running the class in one window and `ps -ef | more` in another, I was not able to see the command, even though I was sure it was running.

Comment: @StrayChild01 I cannot help you any further without knowing what operating system you use. Do you use a linux (which one)? AIX? BSD (which one)? Some other Unix implementation? Have you read the man page for top already? (`man top`)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't answer you directly. I just updated the question and I thought you saw it. It is Solaris 9. I was told that pstak could also work.

Comment: My Solaris Skills are not good enough to tell. But as far as I understood the manpage it should behave the same on it. So this page http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?top (and my man page) says `top -c` should give you what you need. You should flag that question to be moved to serverfault where more Solaris able people will look at it.

Comment: Hi Angelo, I continued searching and I was able to find the whole thing with `ptree | grep MyMainClass`. Thank you so much.